# Unknown table in MULTI DELETE

Tags: mysql

This query gives me an error in MySQL 5.1.57, works in 5.1.53 though:

```
    DELETE f
    FROM table1 AS f
    JOIN table2 AS dsy
    JOIN table3 AS ds
    JOIN table4 AS dp
    JOIN table5 AS dg
    WHERE
    dsy.f1 = f.f1
    AND ds.f2 = f.f2
    AND dp.f3 = f.f3
    AND dg.f4 = f.f4
    AND dsy.school_year = 2011
    AND ds.id = 29620
    AND dp.id = 14120
    AND dg.grade_level = 5;
```

The error is: Unknown table 'f' in MULTI DELETE

Thanks!

EDIT:
Actually this query works, the thing is I was using the schema name to declare my tables like schema.table1 (I removed it to post a more clear query here), with the schema name it breaks...

Comment: Have you tried replacing the "f" alias on the first line with the actual table name?

There's a bug report for it.  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27525 .  Fix appears to be in 5.2 only?

Comment: Doesn't work to do DELETE table1 ... , the error is the same, Unknown table 'table1' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: If the error occurs in a multi-database query, you'll have to prefix the aliases with the database name. ie `DELETE db1.a FROM db1.table1 a JOIN db2.table2 b LEFT JOIN ...`

Comment: My last comment is only true for mysql 5.1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this query -

```
DELETE f
FROM table1 AS f
JOIN table2 AS dsy
  ON dsy.f1 = f.f1
JOIN table3 AS ds
  ON ds.f2 = f.f2
JOIN table4 AS dp
  ON dp.f3 = f.f3
JOIN table5 AS dg
  ON dg.f4 = f.f4
WHERE
  dsy.school_year = 2011 AND ds.id = 29620 AND dp.id = 14120 AND dg.grade_level = 5;
```

Comment: This one works, thanks all for your help! The weird thing is I remember doing something like that a long time ago and that was not working, it's why I put everything in the WHERE...

Comment: EDIT: actually my original query works, the thing is I was using the schema name to declare my tables like schema.table1, with the schema name it breaks...

Comment: Including the schema was killing it for me too. I had to do "USE `myschema`;" in the same query to make it work.

Comment: Note
If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table:

DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...
Table aliases in a multiple-table DELETE should be declared only in the table_references part of the statement. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: It's odd that "USE" is necessary and you can't explicitly call `schema.table`.  I'm reaching MySQL through the C API and `USE` in my case is pretty awkward since it requires me to store and restore the previous context.  This behavior is non-standard and your post is helpful in that it calls it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing all of your table alias? There is a similar solution proposed [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4630). So the following might work:

```
DELETE table1
    FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 
    JOIN table3 
    JOIN table4 
    JOIN table5 
    WHERE
    table2.f1 = table1 .f1
    AND table3.f2 = table1.f2
    AND table4.f3 = table1.f3
    AND table5.f4 = table1.f4
    AND table2.school_year = 2011
    AND table3.id = 29620
    AND table4.id = 14120
    AND table5.grade_level = 5;
```

Comment: that was the issue with mine. maybe you should make the answer a little more clear as to why this works. The question should stand up on its own without a link.

Comment: The gist of the matter is that you should use your table alias in the top `DELETE` part, not the full name of the table.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved same error with using schema after delete:

```
DELETE **`schemaX`.f**
    FROM `schemaX`.table1 AS f
    JOIN table2 AS dsy
    JOIN table3 AS ds
    JOIN table4 AS dp
    JOIN table5 AS dg
    WHERE
    dsy.f1 = f.f1
    AND ds.f2 = f.f2
    AND dp.f3 = f.f3
    AND dg.f4 = f.f4
    AND dsy.school_year = 2011
    AND ds.id = 29620
    AND dp.id = 14120
    AND dg.grade_level = 5;
```