# Pentaho kettle : Below delete doesnt seem to work in SQL script

Tags: pentaho

Ive tried to execute below delete through SQL script in Pentaho Job, I get the error as
Unknown table 'a' in `MULTI DELETE`. Can somebody throw light on this. Is there any other way
to go around this?

```
DELETE a.*  FROM pm_report.PM_CONCERTS_GQV_REPORT_TEST a
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM pm_report.PM_CONCERTS_GQV_REPORT_TEST_3 b WHERE b.TM_EVENT_ID=a.TM_EVENT_ID
GROUP BY b.TM_EVENT_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mysql right?

See similar solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728581/unknown-table-in-multi-delete) - recommends removing the table alias.

Worth noting this is nothing to do with Pentaho, if you did it in a SQL client you'd get the same error. If you don't then the difference is probably in the jdbc driver version - may be worth checking that.

Comment: Thanks Codek, Yes its MySQL, but would like to confirm that the same Delete works well in MYSQL command line

Comment: then it's definitely a driver issue. Check which version of the driver you are using with PDI and make sure it matches your server.  Again; Not a pentaho issue, more of a jdbc/mysql issue.

Answer (score -1):

i can suggest these options:

1. dont use aliases
2. try this directly on your mysql and check if it works for you.
3. dont use pentaho like this : make a transformation and break apart the query to steps 
   with table input and lookup then delete the rows by row_id 
   its a little bit longer but a lot more undersrandable and easy to maintain.
   "dont over optimize"