# PHP Delete row from table1 if row doesn't exist in table2

Tags: php

I have two tables, one is where the actual posts are, and one for posts that are saved.
I want to delete a row from the saved table if a post is deleted from the website

I tried this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `saved` WHERE (SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE ad_id = `saved`.ad_id) LIMIT 1");
```

but this doesn't work. Can't think of how to do it the right way

any help it appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will delete all rows from `saved` which its `saved.ad_id` do not reference to any `ads.ad_id`

```
delete s
from saved AS s 
    left outer join ads as a 
        on a.ad_id=s.ad_id
where a.ad_id is null;
```

More here: [MySql delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

And here: [MySql Multi delete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728581/unknown-table-in-multi-delete)

Comment: mysql_query("DELETE b FROM `saved` AS b LEFT OUTER JOIN `ads` as a ON a.ad_id = b.ad_id WHERE a.ad_id is null;"); I placed this on the saved.php page and refreshed. Then checked the database table and the row of the saved ad is still there

Comment: I read something about CREATE TRIGGER can do this but not sure how to use that

Comment: You can use a OnDelete trigger with InnoDB engine and foreign keys.

Comment: on your mysql_query('') statement, try to remove the ; after the "is null":  mysql_query("DELETE b FROM saved AS b LEFT OUTER JOIN ads as a ON a.ad_id = b.ad_id WHERE a.ad_id is null");

Comment: yeah i fixed that and still no change. i assume simple refreshing the page will re-run the query to see some effect on the database

Comment: Check for errors: if (mysql_query('delete...') === false)
 echo mysql_error();

Comment: i had a stupid mistake with the wrong table name for a. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use left outer join to get the rows exist in table 1 and not exist in table 2 then you can delete it from table 2 using their IDs

Comment: You should show an example of how to do these instead of just naming concepts.

Comment: @JustinWood Well said.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `saved` WHERE `saved`.ad_id not in (SELECT ad_id FROM `ads`)");
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. I put it in the saved.php page and then I deleted the ad from ads.php and I still saw the row in the database 'saved' table..